# What is the equation of the normal to an $n$ dimensional hyperplane and their intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have an $n$ dimensional hyperplane defined by the equation

$\{\mathbf x\mid \mathbf a^T \mathbf x = b\}, \mathbf a \in \mathbb R^n, b \in \mathbb R$

How do I find the equation of the normal to this hyperplane and its intersection to the hyperplane?

Comment: What is your definition of the *normal*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal line (that is, the orthogonal subspace of the hyperplane) is the span of the vector $a$. To find the intersection solve $$y=\lambda a,$$ $$<a,y>=b$$ which gives $\lambda=\frac{b}{|a|^2}$ and $y=\frac{ba}{|a|^2}$.

Comment: Hey you are a genius! But can you provide a reference for your derivation? Further more, what is the meaning of $\lambda$?

Comment: Can you see if I have this right? A hyperplane is an offset plus a subspace i.e. $H = x_o + a^{\perp}$ where $a^{\perp} = \{v| <a,v> = 0\}$. Then the line normal to the hyperplane is given by $H^{n} = a, a = \{y | <a,y> \neq 0\}$,  but I cannot see how $y = \lambda a$, please instruct!

Comment: $y=\lambda a$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ just means that $y$ is on the line spanned by the vector $a$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the line spanned by $(1,3)$ is the set of points $(\lambda, 3\lambda)$. For example, $(2,6)$ is on that line, by taking $\lambda=2$.